# Django. Получение данных из базы данных проекта во время запуска

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Django на маленьком проекте для себя. Проект состоит из нескольких приложений для работы с разными сервисами и приложения для хранения данных конфигураций сервисов: упрощенно на 2-х приложениях:

Приложение `App_Device` - используется для подключения к сетевым устройствам и массовой отправки команд
Приложение `App_Settings` - содержит модели для хранения условно статичных настроек для работы других приложений, например: одна из моделей – создана для добавления и хранения в BD списка сетевых устройств с параметрами подключения, данный список должен использоваться в App_Device при подключении к устройству

```
Project
    App_Service_1
    App_...
    App_Device
    App_Settings
    ...
```

Можно ли каким-то образом организовать получение данных из моделей в `App_Settings` в момент старта web сервера и хранить их в виде переменной(ых), для дальнейшего использования в других приложениях, что бы не дергать постоянно базу данных? Соответсвенно, эти переменные необходимо обновлять, если были внесены какие-то изменения во время работы (например: добавлено еще одно сетевое устройство)
Можно ли организовать получение этих данных, не городя дополнительные костыли в виде скриптов c функциями подключения к бд?

Comment: Зачем так делать? База данных это и есть "переменная", которая хранит все значения и изменяется при необходимости. Кроме того она будет написана на C/C++ поэтому достать оттуда данные намного быстрее чем использовать python

Comment: Я просто не знаю, как сделать правильно и что необходимо для того, что бы получить данные из модели одного приложения для работы другого приложения

Comment: почитайте документацию про модели django

Comment: Чисто гипотетически, любые данные, которые постоянны и нужны в момент старта сервера, нужно помещать в `settings.py`. Но товарищ @Inventor прав - модели существуют не для того, что бы держать массивы данных в памяти. Если вы хотите что-то держать в кеше, то посмотрите в стороне интеграции с redis или другим подобным кеш-хранилищем